# Stop script chrome extension from runing when varaiable meets required criteria

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i created an extension in chrome, when i activate the extension it runs the content.js script once every two seconds looking for an specific value in a page that is constantly changing.

This is my background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab){
  let msg = {
    txt: "hello"
  }
  window.setInterval(function(){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg);
}, 2000);
}
```

And this is the body of the content.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse){

  
  if (message.txt === "hello"){
####
SCRIPT CODE
####
}
}
```

Is it possible to stop my script from runing every two seconds when a specific variable meets certain criteria?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use **sendResponse** callback of **addListener** function in your content script **content.js** to send the response back to your **background script**. In **background scrpit**, you can handle the response to clear the interval.

Background script code:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);

function buttonClicked(tab){
  let msg = {
    txt: "hello"
  }
  let interval = window.setInterval(function(){
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, msg, function(response) {
      if(response.message === "success"){
       clearInterval(interval);
     }
  });
}, 2000);
}
```

content script code:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse){
  if (message.txt === "hello"){
    ####
    SCRIPT CODE
    ####
  }
  //Once your specific variable meets certain criteria, invoke the following line
  sendResponse({message: "success"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the `setInterval` id in a variable, like this:

```
var id=setInterval();
```

Then use `clearInterval` to stop it:

```
clearInterval(id);
```

Also, you don't need `window` before `setInterval`

Comment: I use the following for pesky and annoying sites to "kill" all intervals:  
`newInterval=setInterval(null, 999999);  
for(i=newInterval+1;i>=0;i--) clearInterval(i);`  
`setInterval()` returns the next available integer, so the above "takes care" of any running (or not) interval.

Comment: So, let me see if i understand. in "background.js" i store the set interval id in a variable, and then in "content.js" when a variable meets a criteria, lets say i = 1, in the next line i use clearInterval(id); and it will stop running the script? (sorry, not very good at this)

Comment: Yes, the interval will stop

Comment: But since they are in different files, and functions the var will have to be global

Comment: So instead of using `var id = `, use `window.id = `

Comment: It doesn't work for me, now i have this https://pastebin.com/ayp6w4gG and it's still running every two seconds. What i'm doing wrong?